# how do I render background url CSS :after modified in VueJS

Tags: html, css, sass, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using simple-webpack vuecli to implemet my site. I have a button which has an :after modified which produce a contents with background path url. How can I used the `require` on background-url in css? Seems like inline styling is not working for :after css modified.

**Global SCSS**

```
.btn-green .btn-text:after{
  content: "";
  width: 7px;
  height: 10px;
  background: url('/assets/img/svg/arrow-right.svg') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}
```

**Vue Template**

```
<div class="btn-green universal-shadow">
  <div class="btn-text">GET STARTED</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a relative path otherwise Webpack will interpret it as an actual URL instead of a path to a module that it should require.

```
url('assets/img/svg/arrow-right.svg')
     ^ removed the leading /
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I found out convert the path to image base64 string works fine. But I need a proper solution.